# How to copy files created after ant run

Tags: java, eclipse, ant, eclipse-plugin

My Ant code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project default="plugin_export" name="build">
  <target name="plugin_export">
    <pde.exportPlugins destination="C:\" exportSource="false" exportType="directory" plugins="MyPlugin" useJARFormat="true" allowbinarycycles="true" filename="MyPlugin.jar" qualifier="X" />
    <waitfor maxwait="15" maxwaitunit="minute">
      <copy todir="j:\eclipse-rcp-juno-SR1-win32\dropins\">
        <fileset dir="c:\plugins\">
          <include name="*" />
        </fileset>
      </copy>
    </waitfor>
  </target>
</project>
```

it doesn't work, because I get

> windows_build.xml:8: waitfor doesn't support the nested "copy" element.

pde.exportPlugins part is auto-generated by eclipse and it runs background process that creates jar with a plugin.

I would like to copy that plugin into 3 instances of eclpse I do use and put it in the dropins folder.
How to do it ?

Comment: Does your ant build file have a target which is guaranteed to run after the build is finished? If so, you can override it.

Comment: https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=238383

Comment: Could you move the copy block outside the waitFor. Waitfor is meaningful in checking result such as file. IMHO, it cannot say when directory copy is done.

Answer (score 2):

To get things done after your build has finished, you may use a buildlistener.
Kev Jackson implemented a very useful exec-listener in his presentation =
http://people.apache.org/~kevj/ossummit/extending-ant.html (sources are included in the presentation).
For each build result ( BUILD SUCCESSFUL | BUILD FAILED ) it provides a taskcontainer
 you can put all your stuff in that should run AFTER Build has finished :

```
<exec-listener onSuccess="true">
    <echo>Executing after BUILD SUCCESSFUL...</echo>
    <exec executable="..">
      <arg value="..."/>
    </exec>
    <mail ... />
   ..other tasks
  </exec-listener>
<exec-listener onSuccess="false">
    <echo>Executing after BUILD FAILED...</echo>
    <exec executable="..">
      <arg value="..."/>
    </exec>
    <mail ... />
   ..other tasks
  </exec-listener>
```